# Spring Framework: The document type declaration for root element type "beans" must end with '>'

Tags: java, spring

This is my spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans SYSTEM "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd" PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN">
<beans>
    <bean id="data" class="com.blah.tests.DataProviderClass" />
    <bean id="wdcm" class="com.blah.tests.WebDriverCustomMethods"/>
</beans>
```

When I run my application test, this is the error I get:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
 Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
 lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 82; The document type declaration for root element type "beans" must end with '>'.
```

Im using Spring 3.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" >  

     <bean id="data" class="com.blah.tests.DataProviderClass" />
     <bean id="wdcm" class="com.blah.tests.WebDriverCustomMethods"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: should I leave out the first two lines of my code? I tried this, but I got the same error...

Comment: you have to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. After that my answer.

Comment: Have you removed `!DOCTYPE`?

Comment: There is no explanation for the answer. You are just sharing the code and it not an advisable practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the DTD style is still fully supported:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html

> DTD support?
>
> Authoring Spring configuration files using the older DTD style is still fully supported.
>
> Nothing will break if you forego the use of the new XML Schema-based approach to authoring >Spring XML configuration files. All that you lose out on is the opportunity to have more >succinct and clearer configuration. Regardless of whether the XML configuration is DTD- or >Schema-based, in the end it all boils down to the same object model in the container (namely >one or more BeanDefinition instances).

according to your issue, this is maybe caused by the network, did you try to open http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd directly in the browser?(I think you will get error when you open http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd directly in the browser.)